# Error: Hadoop namenode format: file or directory not found?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hadoop-plugins

I am trying to install Hadoop 2.6 in centos 7.
I have done all the changes in bashrc  and xml files. But whenever I’m trying to run the command “Hdfs namenode format” it is giving the below error. I have set the java path and all other variables. Kindly help me with this. I am attaching the error screen shot

[image: error screen shot]

[image: bashrc file]
[image: hadoop-env.sh file]

Comment: can you post what you get out of `ls -la  /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0......./bin/java`.   By the way, your jvm dir name is too long

Answer (score 0):

It seem you it is not getting java on your location.to be sure you check your java location by command

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

then compare.

Comment: which java Command  show your installed location. some case machine has more than one java installed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i resolved the issue for myself and this may be useful for you my friend user2925298

cd /etc/alternatives  ==>the path for the java you can see is 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64/jre/bin/java

In the config file hadop-env.sh set  the 
Java_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64/jre
and use the same path to bashrc
vim ~./bashrc

set the JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64/jre

Note : do not include bin after jre. as we set the path in bash rc :PATH=JAVA_HOME/bin.

You can check the path in the picture that i highlighted

[image]